# How to remove hyper-v role in the windows 10N hosted on the Azure

Tags: windows, azure, hyper-v, vmware-player

I would like to remove hyper-v role from the windows 10.
I used all methods which I found on the internet.

One of the good link  [enter link description here](https://superuser.com/questions/540055/convenient-way-to-enable-disable-hyper-v-in-windows-8)

All commands works without errors, but after restart windows and run VMware I get error [image]
.

I turned off all hyper-v services, but it doesn't help me. 
[image]

How to remove hyper-v role in the windows 10N hosted on the Azure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running Windows 10 on Azure which means it is a virtual machine. Your commands might work correctly but you won't be able to start another virtual machine inside a virtualized environment.

In Azure your underlying system is Hyper-V you cannot do virtualization inside a virtualized environment.

This is called Nested Virtualization which will be available of Hyper-V from Windows Server 2016. (This is in preview currently.)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/user_guide/nesting

Comment: Did you test hyper-v in the Server 2016 ? Today, I installed Server 2016 candidate 5, but hyper-v didn't work.

Comment: I have not tested yet. But as far as I know nested virtualization will work only from build 10565.

Comment: You wrote: Azure your underlying system is Hyper-V you cannot do virtualization inside a virtualized environment. Why Virtualbox with android VM works on a Windows based on the Azure?

Comment: Probably because Virtualbox is the different hypervisor type.

Comment: This could be that VirtualBox has "software" based virtualization, where if there is no "hardware" hypervisor, all calls are translated in software, offering worse performance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox#Software-based_virtualization